# Ignoring Solr in a Ruby Heroku app if Solr is inaccessible

Tags: ruby, heroku, solr, websolr

I've got a simply Ruby app deployed on Heroku, which uses the WebSolr add-on to support `searchable` indexes. If and when WebSolr is down, the app stops working with 503 service unavailable errors. I wouldn't mind if the app continued to work and indexing didn't work temporarily. Is it possible to ignore Solr outages so that the ruby app continues to function?

Answer (score 0):

You could always set up something like [Sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq) and push your updates into a queue. Then you could have failed requests [retry](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Error-Handling#automatic-job-retry) until they succeed (or expire). That way when connectivity is restored, all of your queued updates would dump into Solr automatically.

Comment: My concern isn't about retries, it's about failing over or simply outright ignoring Solr (and `searchable` columns) whilst keeping the app up and running / responsive, i.e. improve uptime. Due to connectivity issues with Solr, the app stopped working completely.